# WPF DataGrid top-left button set/view Content?

Tags: wpf, button, datagrid

Trying to set the Content property of a WPF DataGrid top-left button at run time. I get the button object using the VisualTreeHelper of the DataGrid object and then I successfully set its Content property, as verified using Snoop while running the application. However, the button text is not visible. I suspect this is because there are UI elements on top of the button that use non-transparent background brushes. Upon reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates) I see a grid that uses storyboards and a rectangle that uses gradient brushes.

Other than editing the WPF DataGrid top-left button style template, what are my options for making the button Content (text) visible?

Comment: Have you considered just putting a control on top of the datagrid? Make it ishitestvisible=false and you could still click the datagrid's button.

Answer (score 0):

You could entirely replace the template.

I'd prefer to bind the text of the textblock to a property in a viewmodel personally.

This could get you started.

Put this in scope of the datagrid like in your window resources or a resource dictionary merged in app.xaml.

```
    <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="Red">
                        <TextBlock Text="X" Foreground="White"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Needs more work, but it shows up on a datagrid sample I have.

( This is something which has dozens of styles from experiments answering questions elsewhere in it ).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(Something funny happens, I am now posting under the same user name as before but SO insists that I must recreate my profile every time I log in. Go figure.)

Thank you Andy for the solution you proposed. For the technical reason above, I am unable to mark this question "Solved".

Now I think a quick way around this is to place a transparent label right on top of the DataGrid button, with IsHitTestVisible = false. I noticed a couple interesting things though:

- It seems the button can have a Grid or a string for Content but not both;
- The button is already created when the DataGrid Loaded event handler runs, e.g., a Click event handler can be added to it; however, setting the Content to a string at this time doesn't change anything. I guess Content changes when the DataGrid is populated.